# let image shrink and replace by another image and then scroll through

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.sky,.water,.underwater{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.sky{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/18r3B.jpg);
  height: 100%;
}

.water{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfgRt.jpg);
  height: 100%;
}

.underwater{
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LCuq.jpg);
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sky"></div>
  <div class="water"></div>
  <div class="underwater"></div>
```

I want [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymMeu.jpg) to be the first thing (full screen) you see when you open the website. I have [the sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18r3B.jpg) and [the water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfgRt.jpg) as seperate images.
If you scroll down, I want '[the water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfgRt.jpg)' image to shrink in height so it looks like your view goes down while it gets replaced by [under water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LCuq.jpg)  (that wasn't visible yet) that's located under it.
When the 'under the water' image reaches the top of [the water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfgRt.jpg) image / the bottom of [the sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18r3B.jpg) image, I want [the sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18r3B.jpg) image just to scroll up together with the 'under water' image.

I had difficulties with explaining this haha but i hope you understand.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I edited my post, it doesn't work at all, but i hope you have an idea of what I want.

Comment: Are you trying to get something like a parallax effect? http://experiments.wemakesites.net/pages/css3-parallax-effect-no-javascript/example/

Comment: No, that’s what the result shows no but what i actually want is by scrolling: 1. ‘Underwater comes up, water shrinks in height, sky is still. 2. Underwater reaches bottom sky, underwater keeps scrolling up, sky scrolls up too. 3. Full page is underwater

Answer (score 0):

You could show us some of the work you already tried, it will help to make your question clearer.

Anyway, is something like that a good start?

```css
.top-contain {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: teal;
}

.sky {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/18r3B.jpg') center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
}

.water {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfgRt.jpg') center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
}

.underwater {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/02/20/10/32/wallpaper-83671_960_720.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<div class="top-contain">
  <div class="sky"></div>
  <div class="water"></div>
</div>
<div class="underwater"></div>
```

Comment: I edited my post, it doesn't work at all yet, but i hope you get the idea. Your code is already way better but it isn't yet what i want exactly. Thanks for the help in advance.